# start/stop a service with install4j?

Tags: install4j

During install I need to stop a service (net stop) and then again start a few steps later. This is will be an existing service and not part of the install. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Run executable or batch file" actions with the "Executable" property set to `${installer:sys.system32Dir}\net.exe` and the appropriate arguments in the "Arguments" property. Note that each argument must be entered on a new line.

Alternatively, if you know the path to the service executable, use can use "Stop a service" and the "Start a service" actions, set the "Service" property to "[Other service executable]" and configure the executable in the "Executable" property.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I had been trying the "Stop a service" action but it was failing. Your "Run executable or batch file" action suggestion helped me see my issue. I updated my executable property and now both "Stop a service" and "Start a service" are working.

Comment: I also need to do this same this for Linux systems. Do you have any tips for that?

Comment: Call `/bin/sh -c "service stop [service name]"` The sh is necessary because you don't know where service is installed. `/bin/sh` is the executable and there are 2 parameters: `-c' and everything in the quotes.

Comment: and I'll need to use "Run executable or batch file"? "Stop a service" or "Start a service" actions will only work for Windows? I apologize for how basic my questions are, I have not worked with install4j for very long.

Comment: Yes, use the "Run executable or batch file". You can use the "Start/Stop a service" if you know the path to the executable and it won't work for systemd.